# Set intersection using bloom intersection

Tags: bloom-filters

Let $A \subseteq Z$, where $Z=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$. Now given any $B \subseteq Z$, we need to check whether $A \cap B =\varphi$ or not. I am looking for a randomized algorithm.

I am trying to implement it using a bloom filter.
Create a bloom filter for $A$ and $B$ respectively. Now consider the intersection of $A$ and $B$ which means AND operation of $A$ and $B$. Assume that there are $n$ elements in both arrays. Then the number of bits required in bloom filters will be $O(n)$ many bits and $O(n/\log n)$ many words. AND operation is going to take $O(n/\log n)$ time

Is there any better (faster runtime) algorithm for the above problem?

Comment: Partitioned bloom filters have much better FPR when performing set intersection, especially if the goal is to test for disjoint sets. See https://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~steffan/papers/jeffrey_spaa11.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any special knowledge about the distribution of data, you cannot do better than that.  In the worst case, you have to read every element of $B$.  There can be $\Theta(n)$ elements of $B$.  So, every correct algorithm must take at least $\Omega(n/\log n)$ time in the transdichotomous model, where you can read an entire $O(\log n)$-size word in 1 step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for an algorithm which can give the result with high probability.